# Keras early stopping callback error, val_loss metric not available

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am training a Keras (Tensorflow backend, Python, on MacBook) and am getting an error in the early stopping callback in fit_generator function.  The error is as follows:

```
RuntimeWarning: Early stopping conditioned on metric `val_loss` which is not available. Available metrics are:
  (self.monitor, ','.join(list(logs.keys()))),
RuntimeWarning: Can save best model only with val_acc available, skipping.

'skipping.' % (self.monitor), RuntimeWarning
[local-dir]/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py:497: RuntimeWarning: Early stopping conditioned on metric `val_loss` which is not available. Available metrics are:
  (self.monitor, ','.join(list(logs.keys()))), RuntimeWarning
[local-dir]/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py:406: RuntimeWarning: Can save best model only with val_acc available, skipping.
  'skipping.' % (self.monitor), RuntimeWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  :
  [my-code]
  :
  File "[local-dir]/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "[local-dir]/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 2213, in fit_generator
callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)
  File "[local-dir]/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py", line 76, in on_epoch_end
callback.on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)
  File "[local-dir]/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py", line 310, in on_epoch_end
self.progbar.update(self.seen, self.log_values, force=True)
AttributeError: 'ProgbarLogger' object has no attribute 'log_values'
```

My code is as follows (which looks OK):

```
:
ES = EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", min_delta=0.001, patience=3, mode="min", verbose=1)
:
self.model.fit_generator(
        generator        = train_batch,
        validation_data  = valid_batch,
        validation_steps = validation_steps,
        steps_per_epoch  = steps_per_epoch,
        epochs           = epochs,
        callbacks        = [ES],
        verbose          = 1,
        workers          = 3,
        max_queue_size   = 8)
```

The error message appears to relate to the early stopping callback but the callback looks OK.  Also the error states that the val_loss is not appropriate, but I am not sure why... one more unusual thing about this is that the error only occurs when I use smaller data sets.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I up-voted the previous answer as it gave me the insight to verify the data and inputs to the `fit_generator` function and find out what the root cause of the issue actually was.  In summary, in cases where my dataset was small, I calculated `validation_steps` and `steps_per_epoch` which turned out to be zero (0) which caused the error.

I suppose the better longer-term answer, perhaps for the Keras team, is to cause an error/exception in `fit_generator` when these values are zero, which would probably lead to a better understanding about how to address this issue.

Answer (score 35):

If the error only occurs when you use smaller datasets, you're very likely using datasets small enough to not have a single sample in the validation set.

Thus it cannot calculate a validation loss.

Comment: Tip: Check the number of samples in the validation. I had 0 samples due a bug :P Problem fixed

Comment: As an explanation, you need similar line to this to be added to the model.fit() :   

"validation_data"=validation_dataset

given that validation_dataset is non-empty of course!

Comment: Check you valid dataset size, if it is smaller than batch_size, then this error may occur.

Answer (score 10):

The error occurs to us because we forgot to set validation_data in fit() method, while used `'callbacks': [keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=1)],`

Code causing error is:

```
self.model.fit(
        x=x_train,
        y=y_train,
        callbacks=[keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=1)],
        verbose=True)
```

Adding `validation_data=(self.x_validate, self.y_validate),` in fit() fixed:

```
self.model.fit(
        x=x_train,
        y=y_train,
        callbacks=[keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=1)],
        validation_data=(x_validate, y_validate),
        verbose=True)
```

Answer (score 4):

This error is occur's due to the smaller dataset,to resolve this,increase the train times and split the train set in 80:20.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that I called these Callbacks with the parameter "val_acc".
The right parameter is "val_accuracy".

This solution was in my Error messages in the sentence: "Available metrics are: ..."

Comment: Thanks this solved the problem for me

Answer (score 1):

I got this warning too. It appeared after [switching to the master branch of Keras 2.2.4 to get validation_freq functionality enabled][1]:

```
//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/callbacks/callbacks.py:846: RuntimeWarning: Early stopping conditioned on metric `val_loss` which is not available. Available metrics are: loss,accuracy
  (self.monitor, ','.join(list(logs.keys()))), RuntimeWarning
```

However, despite of the warning, early stopping on `val_loss` still works (at least for me). For example, this is the output I received when the computation early stopped:

```
Epoch 00076: early stopping
```

Before that Keras update, early stopping worked on `val_loss` with no warning.

Don't ask me why it works because I haven't a clue.

(You can try this behavior with a small example that you know it should early stop).

Answer (score 0):

I got this error message using fit_generator.   The error appeared after the first epoch had finished.

The problem was that I had set validation_freq=20 in fit_generator parameters.

Keras executes the callbacks list at the end of the first epoch, but it didn't actually calculate val_loss until after epoch 20, so val_loss was not (yet) available.

Setting validation_freq=1 fixed the problem.

Comment: Setting `validation_freq=1 fixed the problem.` and doing nothing else resolves this?

Comment: Hi Nelles, Yes, for me it did solve the problem.  For most people, the root cause is more complicated, and so for most people it will not solve the problem.   As you can see from the other answers, the symptom "val-loss metric not available" can be caused in different ways.   If you have validation_freq > 1 for fit_generator, and the error message appears after your first epoch, then it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

using `tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()` will solved the problem. Trying validation_freq = 1 is also a good idea. However, you have to wait for the script terminal output for each epoch complete
[image: Like this result]
Therefore, I recommend to observe the result by tensorboard, weight&bias, etc,...

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using tf.keras when importing dependencies. It works for me when I directly use Keras (e.g., to import layers and callbacks).

Answer (score 0):

you should set the **monitor** parameter for early_stop.
default value of **monitor** parameter for early stop is "val_loss"

```
keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5)
```

and when you do not set validation_set for your model so you dont have val_loss.

so you should set **validation_set** for your model inside "fit" function or change the **monitor** parameter value to "loss"

```
keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', patience=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line from

```
'val_loss'
```

to

```
'loss'
```

```
ES = EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", min_delta=0.001, patience=3, mode="min", verbose=1)
```

change to...

```
ES = EarlyStopping(monitor="loss", min_delta=0.001, patience=3, mode="min", verbose=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, check your `validation_freq` input as `val_loss` parameter is only available after it is computed the first time.

i.e. if your early stoping method stops at epoch 5 and your `validation_freq` is set to 10, the `val_loss` won't be available

The early stopping keras callback requires you to compute the `val_loss` on each epoch for the monitoring purpose

Answer (score 0):

If you are too lazy - try something like this.
Quite often EarlyStopping would fail because it runs too soon. Setting "strict" to "false" allows to avoid crashing after failing to check the metrics. "verbose" would also write what happened, so you can confirm that it stopped crashing after the first epoch.

```
EarlyStopping(
 monitor="val_loss",
 mode="min",
 verbose = True,
 strict=False)
```